# When to use custom c# events

Tags: c#, oop, events, event-handling

When is it appropriate to raise an event in C#?

As an example, in our system we have data objects being sent to us, say 50 per minute, from an external system.  Upon receiving a data packet, we need to have it processed by another object.  Would an event or a simple method call be better to use in this situation?

An event seems like a natural fit intuitively, but I'm not clear as to what advantage this may offer as compared to simply using a regular method call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Events should be used when it is inappropriate for the code which originates the action to have direct knowledge of the code(s) which react to that action.

On one hand, an event does sound appropriate here, because the code which handles data reception should not be dependent on the implementation of the code which does something with said data. Otherwise the data reception code is now responsible for two things - receiving the data *and* delegating the processing of it.

On the other hand, if the particular processing of the data is directly tied to act of it being sent by the external caller, it may make more sense to make it a function call. We don't really have enough information in your question to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

IMO using a Queue would be an appropriate first step. Code processing the Queue can in turn either raise events or accept a delegate which performs different tasks based on the kind of data object. Action or Func  should work well here.

Remember that when you use events, you have to ensure that handlers get unregistered in a timely manner or else you could have leaks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case an event doesn't make sense. Events tend to be to inform about what is going on, not to replace function calls.  They are more informative.

So, you may want to pass in an Action<> function, so that you can then call the function that was passed in, to do the processing.

This would be better than a function call, IMO.

You can look at this page for an example:
http://www.claassen.net/geek/blog/2007/12/action-func-never-write-another.html

Update: If you are not using C#3 then you may want to use a delegate instead, which, an event handler is a specialized delegate.

Comment: I don't agree with the "not to replace function calls" statement.  Event handlers ARE function calls.  An event is intended to be used to give code (functions) a chance to execute when a condition is met in a decoupled manner.  Think of controls; they give imperative code (functions) the chance to run when the user does something.  Another thing to note is that event handlers ARE delegates, and thus passing an Action and passing an EventHandler is the same thing; they just have different signatures.  That being said, I'm a BIG user of the Action delegate class

Comment: From a patterns perspective what you're describing is practically the same as eventing, except requiring exactly one subscriber.

Comment: I tend to prefer just passing in Action<> functions as it gets rid of needing delegates and it simplifies my code, I believe, making it more flexible.